# Detecting if the browser window is moved with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows, browser, dom-events

This is for a demo... and i was just curious, can you detect if the window has been moved? Like if you move Firefox/Chrome/IE around your monitor? I doubt it, but I wanted to see since you can check for resize and focus/blurred windows.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can only think of this (heavy) work-around, where you check if `window.screenX` and `window.screenY` have changed every x milliseconds

```
var oldX = window.screenX,
    oldY = window.screenY;

var interval = setInterval(function(){
  if(oldX != window.screenX || oldY != window.screenY){
    console.log('moved!');
  } else {
    console.log('not moved!');
  }

  oldX = window.screenX;
  oldY = window.screenY;
}, 500);
```

Though I would not recommend this -- it might be slow and I'm not sure if screenX and screenY are supported by all browsers

Comment: `screenX` and `screenY` are not supported in IE, which has similar but not completely equivalent `window` properties `screenLeft` and `screenTop`.

Comment: Clever hack! Never even thought about that.

Comment: `screenX` and `screenY` are supported as of IE9 ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_screenx.asp))

Answer (score 10):

A potentially more optimised version of this is to only check for window movement when outside of the window combined with Harmen's answer:

```
var interval;
window.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt){ 
  if (evt.toElement === null && evt.relatedTarget === null) {
    //if outside the window...
    if (console) console.log("out");
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      //do something with evt.screenX/evt.screenY
    }, 250);
  } else {
    //if inside the window...
    if (console) console.log("in");
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
});
```

If using jQuery, it may normalise screenX/Y in this case so it's worth running a few tests on that. Jquery would use this format instead of `addEventListener`:

```
$(window).on('mouseout', function () {});
```

If you are moving the window in Windows OS via <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, and find that windows resizes are ignored, I would recommend adding an extra level of detection via `keypress` events.

Comment: Great idea. You made me rethink my problem. Instead of trying to hide something while the user is dragging a window, I will hide it on mouseout and bring it back on mouse in.

Comment: Windows users can move windows by keyboard (Alt+Space). Your code can miss such moves.

Comment: Good to know! Any clues on what to look into for that?

Comment: Ah, I see, because it doesn't run the interval... adding idea for fix now.

Comment: The user can still manipulate the window through keyboard shortcuts such as on Windows `[Meta]` + `[Right']` || `[Left]` between different size states and monitors.

Comment: Could you tell me if keypress events register to the active window at the same time? These should come through in targeting. If that is the case then it may be possible to kill that event via `preventDefault()`? I suspect not but worth a shot.

Answer (score 8):

Re the first answer: I use the 'poll window position' in production code. It's a very lightweight thing to do. Asking for a couple of object properties twice a second is not going to slow anything down. Cross-browser window position is given by:

```
function get_window_x_pos()
{
   var winx;

   if(window.screenX)
      winx=window.screenX;
   else if(window.screenLeft)
      winx=window.screenLeft;

   return winx;
}
```

and similarly for vertical position. In my code I use this to fire an AJAX event off to the server to store position and size of the window so next time it will open where it was the last time (I'm probably moving to HTML5 local storage soon.) One little wrinkle you might want to cover is not generating spurious updates while the window is being dragged. The way to handle this is to register when the window has been moved for the first time and only trigger an update when two subsequent polls of window position return the same value. A further complication is for windows which allow resizing from all sides. If the left or top side are dragged, the DOM will give you a resize event, but the nominal window position will have altered as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. The DOM is only notified about window sizes, cursor positions, "focus" and "blur", etc; anything that affects *drawing*. Since moving a window doesn't necessarily require any of the contents to be "redrawn" (in a Javascript/Html engine sort of sense), the DOM, therefore, doesn't need to know about it.

Comment: "Doesn't need to know about it" is wrong (or else nobody would be asking about it), but correct that there seems to be no way (even in 2022).  Strange username.

Comment: A window being moved doesn't require any of the contents to change. Your apps should not be dependent on window position. It's also a privacy concern. My username has plenty of context if you search around a bit, not sure what that has to do with my answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no. Although I did find [this page](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/window.html) that claims there is such a thing. I tested that in IE, Chrome, and FireFox, no luck.

Comment: The `move` event of window objects only ever existed in Netscape 4.

Comment: @Tim Down: sad, sad browser that one was.. thanks for the info!