# Get window position on close

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that creates popups in a static location. However, if the user moves the popup and then closes it. I'd like to set the next popup to open in the same location the previous one was closed.

My background page is already listening for onRemoved and onFocusedChanged, but those only return the Window ID.

Is there a way to get the last `top` and `left` locations of a popup window after a user moves it, and on or before it is closed?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an eventlistener for that but heres something that might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319487/detecting-if-the-browser-window-is-moved-with-javascript

Comment: Thanks @noa-dev, I did find that, and am testing that out now from within a content script updating my background page, was hoping for something less of a work-around and a more guaranteed on close position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `beforeunload` event and we need a synchronous method of saving data in order to guarantee it successfully completes before the execution context of the page is destroyed.

**If the popup runs your extension page.**

Popup's page script can save the size in the synchronous localStorage shared between all your extension pages, including the background script where you can use the saved value next time to create the popup window.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
  localStorage.windowSize = JSON.stringify({
    left: window.screenX,
    top: window.screenY,
    width: window.outerWidth,
    height: window.outerHeight,
  });
});
```

**If the popup runs a web URL.**

We'll have to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) where we can abuse [chrome.runtime.connect](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connect) to pass the data synchronously in the port name to the background script which will parse and save the data in chrome.storage.local. Of course you can use this approach for the first case as well.

- content script:

  ```
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    chrome.runtime.connect({
      name: 'windowSize:' + JSON.stringify({
        left: window.screenX,
        top: window.screenY,
        width: window.outerWidth,
        height: window.outerHeight,
      })
    });
  });
  ```

  Make sure the content script runs inside the popup, for example, via chrome.tabs.executeScript in your background script right after creating the popup window.
- background script:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
    if (port.name.startsWith('windowSize:')) {
      const windowSize = JSON.parse(port.name.slice('windowSize:'.length));
      chrome.storage.local.set({windowSize});
    }
  });
  ```

Comment: Working perfectly! 'beforeunload' is just what I wanted. I used chrome.runtime.sendMessage() to send and save the window position in my background page instead of chrome.runtime.connect().

Comment: I didn't want to use sendMessage because it's internally two steps (connect + postMessage) so I'm afraid it might get blocked sometimes depending on how slow/fast the computer is.