# Is there a way to detect from which side the browser window is reduced/resized using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, browser

In my application, I want to perform different activities based on the window resize from left, right, top, bottom side. If the window is resized from left side, perform A activity, if window is resized from right side, perform B activity and the same for top and bottom. Preferred platforms/languages - JavaScript/jQuery, Angular 8+, CSS.

thanks.

Comment: Nah, I don’t see any real way to do that. Using `screen.top` and `screen.left` plus the current window height & width that might work - but those properties appear to be Firefox-only, not supported by other browsers. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/top#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: And in general, I doubt whether this is such a good idea to begin with - with tabbed browsing, I don’t know how many users are even “resizing browser windows” any more these days? My browser is set to not even allow any custom-sized popups any more, but open those in standard size tabs as well.

Comment: @CBroe just to add - I do occasionally resize windows but it's when I want to tile two browsers next to each other on the screen. Since that's achieved by Win + <arrow> automatically by the OS/window manager, I don't even know which way is the window resized. I can only assume the window size is directly set, rather than directionally changed.

Comment: You can use the window.resize event but this will permit you to detect a change in the x or y  direct by checking the height and width on resize. A difference in width will mean an increase/decrease from left or right while a difference in height will mean an increase/decrease from top or bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced there is a sure fire way of doing this for all browsers, all combinations of multiple monitors, all possibilities for ways of moving a window, but you can get quite a way there by using:

`window.screenX` etc to remember where the window was last time you looked

trying to detect if the window has been moved by other means - see for example [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319487/detecting-if-the-browser-window-is-moved-with-javascript](http://trying%20to%20detect%20if%20the%20window%20has%20been%20moved%20by%20other%20means%20-%20see%20for%20example%20%5Blink%5Dhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319487/detecting-if-the-browser-window-is-moved-with-javascript) @marksyzm 's answer which detects mouseout of the window and remembering screenX etc if so (or, more hacky but possibly more reliable, checking with setTimeout several times a second)

detecting resize and see if the window has moved plus what its width now is from which you can tell if it was resized from the left or right and so on.

Comment: Will give it a shot. Thanks A Haworth.

Thank you everyone.